# How can accessibility checker handle "no content errors" when using template variables?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, accessibility, uiaccessibility

This is my code:

```
<h3>{{$ctrl.fieldTemplate.label}}</h3>
```

Checker using WAVE:

[image]

WAVE is not picking up data from template variables

[image]

Comment: Doesn't [WAVE](https://wave.webaim.org/) scan the generated code and not the html source? That is, I thought template variables would be evaluated and then the code is scanned. If you do a "view > source" on the heading, does it show the template variable or the **value** of the variable?

Comment: @slugolicious no value at all